# WhereNot clause are not working in laravel7

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**I used **whereNot** clause in my following script . that is showing following error.The rest of the data will show except the **cancel** data. can any one help me.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'not' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `client` as `c` left join `users` as `u` on `c`.`telemarketar` = `u`.`id` left join `disposition` as `d` on `c`.`id` = `d`.`client` where `not` = bgcolor)**

```
 $datas= DB::table('client as c') 
                     ->select(
                    'c.id as clid',
                    'u.id as uid',
                    'd.id as did',
                    'd.bgcolor as bgcolor',
                    'd.fcolor as fcolor',
                    'c.customerName as customerName',
                    'c.email as email',
                    'c.streetaddress as streetaddress',
                    'c.city as city',
                    'c.landNumber as landNumber',
                    'u.codenumber',
                     )       
                     ->leftJoin('users as u', 'c.telemarketar', '=', 'u.id')
                     ->leftJoin('disposition as d', 'c.id', '=', 'd.client')
                     ->whereNot('bgcolor','=','CANCEL')
                     ->orderBy('c.id', 'desc')        
                     ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this .

```
$datas= DB::table('client as c') 
                     ->select(
                    'c.id as clid',
                    'u.id as uid',
                    'd.id as did',
                    'd.bgcolor as bgcolor',
                    'd.fcolor as fcolor',
                    'c.customerName as customerName',
                    'c.email as email',
                    'c.streetaddress as streetaddress',
                    'c.city as city',
                    'c.landNumber as landNumber',
                    'u.codenumber',
                     )       
                     ->leftJoin('users as u', 'c.telemarketar', '=', 'u.id')
                     ->leftJoin('disposition as d', 'c.id', '=', 'd.client')
                     ->where('bgcolor','<>','CANCEL')
                     ->orderBy('c.id', 'desc')        
                     ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `whereNot()` function in Laravel. You're looking for:

```
...
->where('bgcolor', '!=', 'CANCEL')
...
```

The reason you're getting that error is that `->where{Noun}()` is a magic function in Laravel, where `{Noun}` is used as as column in the query (unless it exists as a specific function, like `->whereHas()`).

Since there is no `->whereNot()` function, it's using `not` as a column: name:

```
WHERE `not` ...
```

and this is invalid, as indeed your tables does not have a `not` column.

Comment: yes realize how to solve this and what will be right code

Comment: replace `->whereNot('bgcolor','=','CANCEL')` with `->where('bgcolor', '!=', 'CANCEL')`, exactly as I said in my answer...

Comment: ->where('bgcolor', '!=', 'CANCEL') i used this but i dont get all data.

Comment: That's a separate issue. The answer I provided was to address the error you posted. If the error is gone, consider accepting this answer and closing your question. You'll have to modify your question a lot if you want to change your question to "why am I not getting data", which would invalidate the answers and goes against how to use Stackoverflow.